# I want to save how many button clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I want to save how many button print was click, and save it to database.

example:

```
<script>
count = 0;

function increment(){
count++;
return count;
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" />
<a href="#" onclick='increment()'>Print</a>
```

is this correct?

so when the Print clicked the count value will save to database

Answer (score 0):

Your code will increment the value of **count** each time Print is clicked but it then does nothing with the variable. (The return statement here does nothing.)

This means it won't endure beyond a page refresh.  You need to then implement the code that saves it to a database or some kind of storage.

Your question is tagged with a PHP tag but no accompanying code. You can certainly use php to save the data in say a MySql database or even just log it to a file.

Have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
and https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Hope that steers you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
count = 0;

function increment(){
count++;
// make xhr request to server and save count in db

//return count;
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" />
<a href="#" onclick='increment()'>Print</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).